# Stripe.net - Payments, backend

Tags: stripe-payments

So far, I'm striking out with google.  Trying to toy around with Stripe.  Now, cybersource, payflo, authorize.net all talk direct to the backend when it comes to entering credit card data.  I've been trying to figure out how do the same with Stripe.  I can't find out how to do it without stripe.js.

ie:  Enter credit card through generic form, once posted to server, the server calls stripe (using new paymentintent because of SCA).  In short, I need to know how to create the credit card object on the backend so I can send it to the payment intent without stripe.js.

I do NOT have code snippets of my own since I'm just now learning the API.  Don't know if this is even possible/allowed/etc.

Edit:  Everything follows this general premise: https://careydevelopment.us/blog/how-to-implement-a-credit-card-payment-solution-with-spring-boot-and-the-stripe-api

Comment: I believe you need to edit your post and add a clear question.

Comment: Edited. I just need to get the credit card data to the payment intent without stripe.js.

Comment: "get the credit card data to the payment intent without stripe.js" — you don't. You *must* use stripe.js unless you are a PCI certified entity, certified to directly handle raw credit card details and will submit a SAQ declaration to that affect from your auditors https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance There are ways to do it but Stripe doesn't document them because they're not the recommended paths.

Comment: OOC, why don't you want to use stripe.js? Or Stripe Checkout?

Comment: My client is PCI certified, or at least will be before the product goes live.  As for not wanting to use stripe.js, I need a single form that will dole out required info to the various processing API's.  Also, desktop apps may be in play, which eliminates javascript.